# How to Speedup Printing PDFs?

Tags: pdf, printing

Is it possible to tune the PDF file so it can print faster?

Comment: What do you mean?  Are you printing to the PDF file or are you printing a PDF that already have..

Comment: This question is very unclear, and still hasn't been clarified over a week later...

Answer (score 2):

You can tune a PDF file to allow it to print faster.

- Using Acrobat Professionnal in the Advanced menu you will find the PDF Optimizer... option.
- If you want to further optimize, you can use [Enfocus PitStop](http://www.enfocus.com/product.php?id=855)

Answer (score 0):

ehh?

Printing to PDF or Printing to a printer from PDF?

You could always try another PDF viewer if you are talking about it opening slow.

If you are talking about it printing to a printer slow, get a new printer!

If you are talking about printing to a virtual PDF printer, try another one.

Comment: I didn't even think of actually sending it to the printer..I thought he meant taking a file and sending it to the "PDF Printer" which would save it as a PDF file. I'm going to feel dumb if that wasn't the case.

Comment: lol - I really have no idea - "Is it possible to tune the *PDF file* so it can print faster?" I thought the same as you, but he mentions PDF file, so I assume he already has it and wants to print... Question was way to vague.

Comment: I also thought this was about printing already created PDFs, not printing TO PDF. May I suggest changing the title to "Creating PDFs" or "printing to PDFs". For "printing PDFs" tells just that - that you have a PDF and wish to print it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older post, but just in case someone stumbles upon this...

The speed of PDFs can greatly depend on your printer and print driver.  If this is an office printer, make sure they have the PostScript drivers available.  You'll get far better quality as well as performance.

Additionally, you want to look at the memory on your printer and potentially add to it (if available).

I would start with your drivers though, as this is the cheapest option.  Testing with different file sizes can help determine if memory is something you need.

Answer (score 0):

Print to Image.  Click on Advanced and check "Print to Image."  That should help.

Comment: In what program? This isn't a good answer because you aren't providing very much detail.

Answer (score -1):

I would imagine that the more graphics and "drawing" that is required, the longer it is going to take to encode all of that into the PDF file.

Simple is faster.

Other than that I can't think of how you would speed up the process outside of having better hardware. It's not the same as a printer where you can switch it over to "fast draft" mode and it will just blaze through in a shaky black and white image (good enough for most normal usage)

Comment: adjusting the print quality settings is the only way to speed up PDF printing i'm aware of. +1